# Jquery Validation Engine Customizing

Tags: jquery, validation, requiredfieldvalidator, jquery-validation-engine

I want to validate a text field which only allows alphanumeric and `/` symbol. I am using jquery validation engine for validating text fields.

I already tried `class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]"` for allowing only letters.

Can anyone tell me how to customize the above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

add this after including the jQuery and jQuery-validate script files

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("onlyLetterSp", function(value, element, param) {
    if (!value) return true;
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+$/.test(value);
}, 'Alphanumeric or slash Only.');
```

Then use with input field

```
class="validate[required, onlyLetterSp]"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom function for validation as follows.

in html

`class="validate[required,funcCall[check_what_you_need]]"`

in jquery

```
function check_what_you_need(field, rules, i, options){
  if (conditions you need) {
     // this allows the use of i18 for the error msgs
     return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a class to your *jquery.validationEngine-en.js* ( assuming you have the English version of the validation messages), something like this :

```
"onlyLetterSp": 
{                   
  "regex": /^[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+$/,
  "alertText": "* Alphanumeric characters only"
},
```

and then in your html control,

```
class="validate[custom[onlyLetterSp]]"
```

Hope that helps  :)

Answer (score 0):

For Polish signs:

```
{"regex":/^[a-zA-ZąĄęĘżŻźŹćĆńŃłŁóÓ\ \']+$/,"alertText":"* Tylko litery"}
```

Remember to ad **charset="utf-8"**

```
<script src="jquery.validationEngine.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If still have a problem check file encoding ([Wikipedia - BOM](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOM_(informatyka)))